# How to mock ObjOutlookApplication.Session.Stores using Moq.Mock or Rhino.Mocks

Tags: c#, moq, outlook-addin, rhino-mocks

I am developing Outlook Addin using c# code. I am writing a unit test case for the below-listed method. I am stuck at one point.

Can anyone help me to write a unit test case for the below-listed method?

Sample Code:

```
Public bool IsMyPstStoreIsAvailable(string strStoreID)
{
  foreach (Store objStore in ObjOutlookApplication.Session.Stores)
  {
       if(objStore.StoreID == strStoreID)
          return true; 
  }
  return false;
}
```

here, I want to Mock ObjOutlookApplication.Session.Stores and try to cover foreach for line coverage.

How can I mock this object?

I have tried with **Moq.Mock** or **Rhino.Mocks**. But I am not gettings any proper solutions from that.

Sample of unit test case code:

```
[TestMethod]
public void T0005_IsMyPstStoreIsAvailableMoq()
{
   Moq.Mock<Outlook.Application> objMockApplication = null;
   Moq.Mock<Outlook.NameSpace> objMockNameSpace = null;
   Moq.Mock<Outlook.Stores> objMockStores = null;
   Moq.Mock<Outlook.Store> objMockStore = null;  
   try
   {
   objMockApplication = new Moq.Mock<Outlook.Application>();
   objMockStores = new Moq.Mock<Outlook.Stores>();
   objMockStore = new Moq.Mock<Outlook.Store>();
   objMockNameSpace = new Moq.Mock<Outlook.NameSpace>();

objMockFrmOurlookWatcher.Setup(x => x.GetApplicationObject()).Returns(objMockApplication.Object);

objMockApplication.Setup(x => x.Session).Returns(objMockNameSpace.Object);

objMockNameSpace.Setup(x => x.Stores).Returns(objMockStores.Object);

objIFrmOurlookWatcher.IsMyPstStoreIsAvailable("ABCD StoreID");                    
    }
    catch (System.Exception ex)
    {
         Assert.Fail("IsMyPstStoreIsAvailableMoq" + ex.Message.ToString());
    }
}
```

Thanks

Comment: The question in its current state is incomplete. Read [ask] and then [edit] the question to provide a [mcve] that can be used to reproduce the problem, allowing a better understanding of what is being asked.

Comment: Unrelated tip: you don't need `try...catch{Assert.Fail}` around the contents of a test. Any uncaught exception will cause the test to fail with better information than your code is offering.